# SVG shapes added to Raphael group fire events as if separate

Tags: svg, mouseevent, raphael

**Imagine this:**

- 2 concentric circles, with the smaller one over the larger one so
  that both are visible
- both are added to a Raphael group (set)
- the group has mouseout and mouseover event handlers

**Problem:**
When the cursor goes from one circle to the other, both event handlers fire, as if they were added separately to each circle.

What I want is for events to be handled for the entire group as if it was a single shape.
How can I achieve that?

Here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.0.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var W=200;
var H=200;
var paper=new Raphael(document.getElementById('target'),W,H);
var c1=paper.circle(W/2,H/2,70).attr({fill:'orange','stroke-width':4,stroke:'red',opacity:0.7});
var c2=paper.circle(W/2,H/2,50).attr({fill:'green','stroke-width':4,stroke:'yellow',opacity:0.7});
var group=paper.set();
group.push(c1,c2);

var count=0;

group.mouseover(function()
{
  console.log('IN',++count);
});
group.mouseout(function()
{
  console.log('OUT',++count);
});
```

and the CSS code:

```
#target{width:200px;}
```

Run the above code and see the results here: http://jsbin.com/ivules/7.

Console shows IN and OUT logs.
Just move the mouse between the two circles' bounds.

Answer (score 0):

For your mouseout() function, please try:

```
group.mouseout(function()
{
  this.mouseout(function(){
    console.log('OUT',++count);
  });
});
```

When you hover over the outer circle, you will get "IN". When you hover over the inner circle, you will get "IN" again. When you leave the circle entirely, you will finally get "OUT".

If that's too many "IN"'s, try creating an invisible circle, place it over top the current 2 circles, and only add the mouseover event to that circle. For instance, try:
      `c3=paper.circle(W/2,H/2,70).attr({fill:'orange','stroke-width':4,stroke:'red',opacity:0});`

```
c3.mouseover(function()
{

    console.log('IN',++count);

});

c3.mouseout(function()
{

    console.log('OUT',++count);

});
```